# When using dockerfile and dockercompose, how can I map a network drive letter?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, windows-container

I have an ASP.NET Core application running in a Windows container.
I need to ensure that the ASP.NET Core application can access a network path like `G:\public`.

I have a Docker file and a compose file which I run `docker-compose up -d`

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["MyApp.exe"]
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

How do I map the network path to a drive letter inside to the container?
For example, using the [`net use`](https://ss64.com/nt/net-use.html) command. Should it be part of the entrypoint?